# Magento2 - Add customer attribute field validation in back end

Tags: magento2, customer, backend, validation

How to add customer level `Custom attribute` field validation like **Validate** that end date is greater than the start date from the backend.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added server-side validation.

> **etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save">
        <plugin name="Customerattr_Plugin" type="Custom\Module\Plugin\Checkattribute" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
    </type>
```

> **Plugin/Checkattribute.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;


class Checkattribute
{

    public function __construct(
        ResultFactory $Redirect, 
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,   
        RequestInterface $request
    )
    {
        $this->resultFactory = $Redirect;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->getRequest = $request;
    }

    public function aroundexecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save $subject,
        $proceed,
        $data = "null",
        $requestInfo = false
    )
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $data = $subject->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (isset($data['customer']) || $data['customer'] != '') {
        //code to validate start and end date
        if (!empty($data['customer']['start_date']) && !empty($data['customer']['end_date'])) {
            if (strtotime($data['customer']['start_date']) > strtotime($data['customer']['end_date'])) {
                $this->_messageManager->addError(__('End date should be greater than start date.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();
                }
            }
        }

        return $proceed();

    }

}
```